# When deploying GA in GTM, when should the script should be fired?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Should it fire during gtm.js, gtm.dom gtm.load, or does it not matter? Google support didn't have any recommendations https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107124?hl=en.

Answer (score 0):

Firing the main GA tag should be done at `Pageview` which is the default for the built-in `All Pages` Trigger. This is normally completely fine. The only reason to change this is if your data depends on elements on the page to be present.

For example: If you are using a tag of type `Transaction` you should set the trigger to `DOM Ready` because GTM will otherwise not be able to pick up the `dataLayer` transaction.